# How to find this kind of relationship: $x-\frac{1}{x}=A$ and $x+\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{A^2+4}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

Could someone explain **how to get from: $x-\frac{1}{x}=A$ to $x+\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{A^2+4}$** ? It is one of the Algebra II tricks.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it can be negative. We need assumption $x>0 $

Comment: I think it should be $A^2+4$ under the square root; see my answer (unless I've done something wrong).

Comment: @BladeofDagger You may want to make some corrections... Did you check what happens if $x=1$?

Comment: Yes, you're right . I've made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by squaring both sides:
$$\begin{align}x-\frac{1}{x}&=A\\\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2&=A^2\\x^2-2+\frac{1}{x^2}&=A^2.\end{align}$$
Then try adding $4$ to both sides and "reversing" the processes above.

Comment: Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it!

$x-\frac{1}{x}=A$

$\Bigl(x-\frac{1}{x}\Bigl)^2=A^2$

$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-2=A^2$

$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=A^2+2$

$\Bigl(x+\frac{1}{x}\Bigl)^2-2=A^2+2$

$\Bigl(x+\frac{1}{x}\Bigl)^2=A^2+4$

$\sqrt{\Bigl(x+\frac{1}{x}\Bigl)^2}=\sqrt{A^2+4}$

$x+\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{A^2+4}$

Comment: You actually get $\left|x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right|=\sqrt{A^2+4}$. Unless you know that $x>0$ you cannot remove the absolute value. Note that the equation $x-x^{-1}=A$ can be rewritten as $x^2-Ax-1=0$, so it has a positive *and* a negative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remark that $x-\frac 1x=A\iff x^2-Ax-1=0$

Which is a quadratics with roots $x$ and $-\frac 1x$.

Calculating $\Delta=A^2+4$ and roots $\dfrac{A\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}$

It is now obvious why their sum is $A$ and their difference is $\sqrt{\Delta}$.